# How can i add a space/empty line between the first and second lines in single string variable?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
string tables = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("tblProducts").InnerText;
            using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(tables))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    // Do something with the line
                }
            }
```

This is what i did now:

```
string tables = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("tblProducts").InnerText;
            StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(@"c:\temp\Table1.txt");
            w.WriteLine(tables);
            w.Close();

            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\Table1.txt");
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                lines[i] = lines[i].Insert(0, "here ADDED TEXT");
            }
```

But instead Insert iwant somehow to Add a new line between line number 1 and line number 2. So if lines contain now 31 lines then in the end it should contain 32 lines a new line between line 1 and line 2.  Not to add a new line to the end but between 1 and 2.

Comment: Grant update my question for the first problem . I want to add a line between line number 1 and 2. empty line like a space/seperate between line 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* you're saying that, given text that looks like this:

```
This is line 1
Second line here
And a third line
```

What you want is:

```
This is line 1
<empty line here>
Second line here
And a third line
```

If so, that should be pretty easy to do:

```
string tables = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("tblProducts").InnerText;
var lines = tables.Split(new[]{Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();
lines.Insert(1, "");
string newText = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);
```

Comment: Working great just needed to switch from lines.Insert("", 1); to lines.Insert(1, ""); Thanks.